# How does Monk guess the exact number of the box in E612?

Tags: monk

In episode 12 of season 6, Monk guesses that most of the product of the theft is still in the bank, in one of the boxes in the vault. So far, so good, I could follow his reasoning.

But I did not understand how he guesses the **exact number** of the box. What is his reasoning **on this precise point** ?

*A posteriori*, when checking the card of that box in the files, the phony name it is registered to,  namely J. A. Guar, confirms his guess.

But he checked only **that particular card**, he did not have to go through all the files. How come?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Monk says, Crawley said that he had half a box full  of jewellery to pawn and that "half a box" is an unusual phrase in this context.

Then Monk says that he remembers that there were only 6 extra large boxes in the vault and only 5 were opened and that one was not the last one in sequence but was in the middle.

Comment: OK !!!!  I understand now what I did **not** understand. First, I watched it in french translation. Second I am rather hard of hearing. Third, I don't have as much flair for detail as Monk.  In french, 6 is "six" and 10 is "dix",with "x" sounded as "s", "z" or mute depending on context but with the same rules fo 6 and 10. And I did not have time to see all the boxes. Since most of the smaller boxes had not been opened, I understood "dix" instead of "six" and wondered how Monk could tell which of the 5 non-opened boxes was the correct one...

Comment: (Pronounced "siss" and "diss", not "sicks" and "dicks")

Comment: "Siss" and "diss", if not immediately followed by the name  of the object, ,or "sees" and "dees"  if immediately followed by the name the objects, beginning by a by vowel; or mute if immediately followed by the name the objects, beginning by a by consonant ? "J'ai mangé "seez" abricots et "dee" pommes. " "Donc tu as mangé "siss" de chaque" (I ate 6 apricots and 6 apples. So you ate 6 of each!) But indeed never sicks nor errr... emmmm.... deeks.

Comment: @Alfred BTW, you can often find scripts online. For instance, https://transcripts.thedealr.net/script.php/monk-2002-1JD2/s6/e12

Comment: @Acccumulation Thanks a lot ! For me and my poor  hearing (my hearing aids do help, but not always quite enough) it might be very useful !

Comment: @Alfred There's also very likely closed captioning.

Comment: *No one* has as much flair for detail as Monk. That's his superpower.